# Restoring a smaller partition image to larger partition using dd

Tags: partition, ext4, dd

I recently backed up an 11GB ext4 partition to a file using dd, repartitioned, and restored the file to a 40GB partition.  parted now shows the partition as 40GB, Nautilus reads it as 11GB, and both list the drive as only having 2GB free.

Is this a filesystem issue or partition issue and how can I fix it without repartitioning to 11GB, dd'ing the file, and growing the partition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all is well up to that point then I think you just need to  `resize2fs` the filesystem up to 40Gb:

```
resize2fs /dev/sdc1
```

where /dev/sdc1 is the name of your partition.

Took off the size as per womble's excellent comment below.

`resize2fs` will grow the filesystem when it's mounted. It can also shrink it but needs to be unmounted for that.

Comment: Don't give resize2fs a size; it'll work out the correct size to expand the filesystem to all by itself, and will get it right, too.

Comment: and for anyone coming across this at a later point, but happens to use reiserfs: `resise_resierfs` :)

Comment: Of course anyone using Reiser should move off ASAP, it's a known dangerous filesystem (no not making the obvious joke). XFS and EXT2/3/4 are the (IMHO) only sane options.

Comment: Thanks. I'm amazed that resize2fs can even be used on a mounted partition.

Comment: @laptop005 i've been using it happily for years now. care to elaborate please :)